# "this.getService is not a function" when changing SAP Fiori title dynamically

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to change SAP Fiori title dynamically i.e. after launchpad is launched and after I clicked on my app of choice, the title of the app should change based on what I want it to be.
I am using this doc page as a guide https://ui5.sap.com/1.54.3/docs/api//symbols/sap.ushell.ui5service.ShellUIService.html.

Inside my `webapp/Component.js`, I have my `setAppTitle()` method which should set a new custom title to the app, and is called from within `onAfterRendering()` method of `webapp/view/S2Custom.controller.js`.

The reason, why I can not call `setAppTitle()` directly from within `init()` method of `webapp/Component.js`, is because I am getting my titles from `webapp/i18n/i18n.properties` which is not "loaded" yet during `Component.js`'s `init()`.

To avoid using something like `setTimeout(() => this.setAppTitle(sTitle), 6000)` inside `Component.js`, I decided to call it from within `onAfterRendering()` method of `webapp/view/S2Custom.controller.js`.

#### webapp/view/S2Custom.controller.js

```js
onAfterRendering: function (oEvent) {
  var sComponentId = sap.ui.core.Component.getOwnerIdFor(this.getView());
  var oComponent = sap.ui.component(sComponentId);
  var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
    bundleName: "ui.s2p.srm.sc.blahblah.BlahBlahExtension.i18n.i18n"
  });
  var oResource = i18nModel.getResourceBundle();
  var sTitle = oComponent.getModel("appModel").getProperty("/sMode") === "OUTBOX" ? oResource.getText("APP_ONE") : oResource.getText("APP_TWO");
  this.getOwnerComponent().setAppTitle(sTitle);
},
```

#### webapp/Component.js

```js
setAppTitle: function (sText) {
  var sTitle = sText;
  console.log("TEST: ", this.getService("ShellUIService")); // ERROR !!!
  try {
    this.getService("ShellUIService").then(function (oService) {
      oService.setTitle(sTitle);
    }, function (oError) {
      jQuery.sap.log.error("Cannot get ShellUIService");
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("TEST - ERROR: ", err);
  }
},
```

The issue in `setAppTitle()` method - the console shows an error:

> this.getService is not a function.

So I went into my `manifest.json`

```json
"sap.ui5": {
  "_version": "1.2.0",
  "services": {
    "ShellUIService": {
      "factoryName": "sap.ushell.ui5service.ShellUIService"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "minUI5Version": "1.28.5",
    "libs": {}
  },
```

I noticed Web IDE showed *Property "services" is not allowed* error on line which contains `"services": {`.

Can you tell me what's causing this problem? I already tried calling `this.getService("ShellUIService")` alone inside `Component.js`'s `init()` method, unfortunately the same error

> this.getService is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using an old UI5 version. The [API `component.getService`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Component#methods/getService) is available only as of `1.37.0`:

> [image: sapui5 sap.ui.core.Component#getService]

You can check your current version by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in the app.

---

About the Web IDE error message..

> I noticed Web IDE showed *Property "services" is not allowed* error on line which contains `"services": {`.

1. If possible, update UI5 resources to one of the [currently supported versions](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html).
2. Except of the root `_version`, remove all other `_version`s in `sap.app`, `sap.ui5`, etc..
3. Set the root `_version` to something **higher than `1.3.0`** according to the table [*AppDescriptor Release and SAPUI5 Version*](https://sap.github.io/openui5-docs/#/Descriptor_for_Applications,_Components,_and_Libraries_be0cf40?id=general-information:~:text=AppDescriptor%20Release%20and%20OpenUI5%20Version).
4. Reload Web IDE.